# Can sign/zero extension be accomplished just by casting?

Tags: c, casting, integer, mips, bit

I have a homework problem (MIPS simulator) which requires for example that we take a 16-bit "immediate" value and sign and/or zero extend it to 32-bits.  I was under the impression that this could be easily accomplished just by casting, such as:

```
uint32_t imm = (uint16_t)IMM_FIELD(instruction); # Zero extend to 32-bits
```

and

```
uint32_t imm = (int16_t)IMM_FIELD(instruction); # Sign extend to 32-bits
```

But then I came across a piece of code online where someone who worked on the same project had written their own "sign_extension8to16", "sign_extension16to32" functions, and these functions worked by shifting the 8 bit number right by 7 and evaluating whether or not the most significant bit (now in the one's place) was 1, then returning a number that is casted to (uint16_t) which masks the upper 8 bits to 0 or 1 accordingly.

Is such an approach really necessary?  I thought that surely casting took care of this already.  The reason I ask is that I'm having very strange error messages and I can't pinpoint the problem, so I figure the reason might be that I'm incorrectly zero and sign extending...

Comment: When you're writing a CPU emulator, keep in mind that your host CPU may use different number formats that what you're emulating. Doing bit work like this explicitly helps ensure that your emulator works correctly if they don't match, or that it's portable to other hosts.

Answer (score 3):

IMO: your method will work.

Let's simplify the problem.

The promotion of `uint16_t` to `uint32_t` and the promotion of `int16_t` to `int32_t` is easy to understand and the expected results occur.  Zero fill unsigned integers and sign extend signed integers.

```
int main() {
  uint16_t u = 65535;
  int16_t i = -1;
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", (uint32_t) u);
  printf("%" PRId32 "\n", (int32_t) i);
  return 0;
}

65535
-1
```

The promotion of `int16_t` to `uint32_t` will first promote the `int16_t` to a `int32_t` and then to a `uint32_t`.  (Actually I think it promote first to `int16_t` to `int` to `int32_t` and then to a `uint32_t` if `sizeof int <= sizeof int32_t` .)  Thus code does a sign-extension before making the result an unsigned integer.

The promotion of `uint16_t` to `int32_t` will promote the `uint16_t` directly to a `int32_t`.  A simple zero extension.

Note: I could be using "promote", when I should say "convert".

```
int main() {
  uint16_t u = 65535;
  int16_t i = -1;
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", (uint32_t) i);
  printf("%" PRId32 "\n", (int32_t) u);
  return 0;
}

4294967295
65535
```